# Pull subnet ID from existing resource

Tags: azure, terraform

In Terraform, I want to build a Azure route table and assign it to an existing subnet.  To do this, I need the subnet_id.  Is there an easy way to pull this information into Terraform?

Below is the route table association resource I am using.

```
resource "azurerm_subnet_route_table_association" "test" {
  subnet_id      = "${data.azurerm_subnet.spoke.subnet_id}"
  route_table_id = "${module.routetable.routetable_id}"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you already set up `data.azurerm_subnet.spoke`, it looks like your mistake is using `subnet_id` instead of just `id`.

```
resource "azurerm_subnet_route_table_association" "test" {
  subnet_id      = "${data.azurerm_subnet.spoke.id}"
  route_table_id = "${module.routetable.routetable_id}"
}
```

The [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/d/subnet.html) shows which values are available under [Attributes Reference](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/d/subnet.html#attributes-reference).

If you haven't set up the data source, it should look something like this:

```
data "azurerm_subnet" "spoke" {
  name                 = "<NAME>"
  virtual_network_name = "<VIRTUAL_NETWORK_NAME>"
  resource_group_name  = "<RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME>"
}
```

Comment: You are a gentleman and a scholar!  Thank you!  Worked like a charm.